# How to import an API/Script.js and use its variables in a VUE project

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm testing an API that helps me with the project I'm working on, and it's possible to install your NPM, its name is "[parallax-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parallax-js#11-installation)", so I looked for how to import, however I didn't have any results in my research, and I can't understand how I import an external script into VUE.

Here's the way I'm trying to put my project together in VUE.

**APP VUE**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">

    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" data-depth="0.2">
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App" data-depth="0.2"/>
  
    {{alpha()}}

  </div>

  
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import '../node_modules/parallax-js/src/parallax.js'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  methods : {

    alpha(){

      let scene = document.getElementById('app');
      let parallaxInstance = new Parallax(scene);

    }

  }
}

</script>
```

The point is ... I want to know how to learn the best way to import an external script ... and how I use the variables and objects inside that script.

Comment: you should do this import Parallax from 'parallax-js'

Comment: I already tried it, it didn't go wrong ... but still I can't use the API ... I can't use its functions as `new Parallax(scene)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{alpha()}}` it is not how you call a method. Usually this is done in mounted hook:

```
mounted() {
  this.alpha()
}
```

Also, it seems that you may want to learn the basics of VueJS, and this is not the right place. You can start with the VueJS documentation provided on their website (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/)

Comment: Ok... this was of great help, but I'm still not able to use the ``new Parallax(scene)`` function from within the script/API

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the comment section you were supposed to import it and finally call your method when vue is mounted.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" data-depth="0.2" />
  <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App" data-depth="0.2" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";
import Parallax from "parallax-js";

export default {
name: "App",
components: {
HelloWorld,
},
methods: {
alpha() {
  let scene = document.getElementById("app");
  let parallaxInstance = new Parallax(scene);
 },
},
 mounted() {
 this.alpha();
 },
};
</script>
```

Comment: That's what Igor Moraru just answered, and in return I will say the same thing ... it makes more sense the way it is calling ``alpha()``... but the ``new Parallax(scene)`` function is not being recognized as a occupation

Comment: I don't really get your last statement if you could come again? Is the parallax still not working?

Comment: So... I solved this by changing the API... in fact, this post from StackOverflow needed to be "closed" or something else... I don't know if I asked the right question... however it is ... what you answered is right... but I think the API is having trouble calling some functions.

Comment: Yes ... but Igor Moraru already answered first he deserves the credit for the answer... I was just waiting for someone who could answer how I could get the script function and use it in my component.